# finding minimum positive value (greater than 0) in an array in VBA

Tags: function, vba, excel

I have an array (AlphaVector) with the following values:

```
-0.2
-0.7
0
0.4
0.3
0.1
```

I want to pick the positive values from the above array and place it in another array named Alpha so that I can pick the minimum positive value from Alpha. My goal is to get the value 0.1 from the above array.
Here's the code I have so far. Alpha gets populated ok as the Msgbox indicates the correct values, but the return value I am getting is 0 instead of 0.1.

```
Function FindMin(AlphaVector)
Dim iCount As Long
Dim N As Integer, i As Integer
N = AlphaVector.Cells.Count
Dim Alpha() As Double
ReDim Alpha(N) As Double
For i = 1 To N
    If AlphaVector(i) > 0 Then
        Alpha(i) = AlphaVector(i)
    Else
        Alpha(i) = 100000000000#
    End If
    MsgBox ("Alpha(i)= " & Alpha(i))
    MsgBox ("AlphaVector(i)= " & AlphaVector(i))
Next i
FindMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(Alpha)
End Function
```

Can you please tell me how to fix it? Also, if there is a more efficient way to write it, perhaps without introducing Alpha, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong index for array `Alpha`. It is zero-based, and since you populate it by using `i`, starting from 1, you leave `Alpha(0)` to be the default, which is 0.

`WorksheetFunction.Min(Alpha)` returns the smallest value, which you now know always will be 0. :-)

You need to redesign your function to handle this. Example will follow shortly.

**EDIT - code sample - updated to work as a UDF**

I finished this sample before I saw your comments, so in my code `AlphaVector` is an array. Anyway, it is always better to explicitly declare any variables and avoid the `Variant` type if you can, which is used if you don't declare variables. This is why I'm using `Option Explicit`. You should too. :-)

There are probably a lot of ways to do what you want, but this is one:

```
Option Explicit

Function FindMin(AlphaVector)
    Dim iNew As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim Alpha() As Variant

    iCount = AlphaVector.Cells.Count

    '***** Use size of AlphaVector
    ReDim Alpha(0 To iCount - 1)
    iNew = 0

    For i = 1 To iCount
        '***** Only save values greater than 0
        If AlphaVector(i) > 0 Then
            Alpha(iNew) = AlphaVector(i)
            '***** Keep track of how many values you save
            iNew = iNew + 1
        End If
    Next i

    '***** Remove any empty items in the Alpha array
    ReDim Preserve Alpha(0 To iNew - 1)

    '***** Reture result of the Min function
    FindMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(Alpha)
End Function
```

Comment: BTW, is `AlphaVector` an `Array` or a `Range` object? You say it's an array, then use `AlphaVector.Cells.Count`?

Comment: I have input the values of `AlphaVector` in Excel in cells E1:E6, so I am treating it as an array. But `AlphaVector.Cells.Count` is what I used for N :-(. I'll await your example :-)

Comment: I tried it and it is returning `#VALUE!`. I copied your code verbatim :-(

Comment: OK, you're using it as a user defined function. That explains the Variant parameter. I will update my code, since it contains a few improvements over your original code - ie you don't need `Alpha` and `AlphaVector` to be the same size.

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI, you can do this in a single cell in Excel with an array function. If your example numbers are in A1:A6 use

```
 =MIN(IF(A1:A6<=0,"",A1:A6))
```

but make sure you enter it with `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` to make it an array formula. VBA not required.

Comment: you have a point. the problem is this is part of a larger function and I also need to find roots of a polynomial, so that is why I need to write VBA :-(

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is how you are setting the dimensions of your `Alpha` variable array. In your code, I assume your module does not have `Option Base 1` declared. As a result, `Alpha` has the dimensions `Alpha(0 to 6)` and as it is a `Double` array, the first, zero element defaults to 0. The easy change is to change your code to:

```
ReDim Alpha(1 to N) As Double
```

Comment: No, I did not have Option Base 1. I added that and it fixed it. I also tried the `ReDim` and that worked as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could change to the below, a bit cleaner:

```
Function FindMinUpdated(AlphaVector As Range)
```

Dim cell As Range
Dim lowValCell As Double

```
lowValCell = Abs(AlphaVector(1))

For Each cell In AlphaVector

    lowValCell = IIf(cell < lowValCell And cell > 0, cell, lowValCell)

Next cell
```

FindMinUpdated = lowValCell

End Function

Comment: tried it, it highlights `IIf` and states `Compile error: Argument not optional`